# Invalid GIU request importing matplotlib.pyplot in Pycharm

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I'm having a problem when calling import `matplotlib.pyplot as plt` in Pycharm console, and I keep getting this error:

> IPython.core.error.UsageError: Invalid GUI request 'qt6', valid ones >are:dict_keys(['none', 'osx', 'tk', 'gtk', 'wx', 'qt', 'qt4', 'qt5', 'glut', >'pyglet', 'gtk3'])

I can't get it to work, can anyone help, please?

Comment: Update your virtual environment. It seems you have some incompatible libraries: mpl has qt6, but ipython seems to be stuck with qt4 and qt5. Else: maybe you installed a very recent released version (it takes some time to have all stack compatible). or check how to change front end engine on mpl (e.g. using wx, or gtk)

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi updating ipython solved it, thank you!